# Restkit: when a foreign key is set to null the relationship in Core Data is not reset

Tags: core-data, restkit, relationship

Basically when a foreign key becomes null (after it was set to a value) the relationship in core data is not reset.

Take as an example the following one-to-many relationship:
contact <<---> company (contact has one company, company has many contacts)

Which is mapped in both directions with the following methods from Restkit:

```
RKRelationshipMapping *contactCustomerRelationshipMapping = [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"contacts" toKeyPath:@"hasContacts" withMapping:contactResponseMapping];
[customerResponseMapping addPropertyMapping:contactCustomerRelationshipMapping];
[contactResponseMapping addConnectionForRelationship:@"forCustomer" connectedBy:@{@"companyID" : @"identifier"}];
```

Then, assume that a contact is linked to a company both in core data and in the remote server, so the JSON returns:
company_id = 123
which is correctly mapped to the relationship in Core Data.

Although when the relationship is null-ed out the returning JSON in response of a GET contact returns:

```
'contact': {
....
address = "20 Wordworth Ave";
city = "<null>";
"company_id" = "<null>";
...
}
```

The company_id is then set correctly in the core data entity but the relationship connection mapper then does not delete the reference to the company with id 123 via the relationship. So it seems like Restkit is not applying the null value of the foreign key to the relationship in Core Data.

I have verified that this happens only when company_id is reset to null and not when the value is changed to another company_id.

Let me know if you have any suggestion on how to solve the issue.
(Right now I am thinking to implement the setter for company_id and manually reset the relationship when it's null)

Thanks a lot!

---

I am using the latest Restkit development branch (which is tagged as 0.21.0 - currently the lastest release is 0.20.3 but blake watters told me that the development branch has already been tagged but he did not have the time to prepare docs)
I am actually using cocoapods and included the latest dev release with the line:
pod 'RestKit', :head

Answer (score 1):

Your workaround should be doable.

This could be classed as a bug in RestKit. As such you'd be better off raising it as an [issue](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues). You can also looking at adding it as a feature.

It's possible that you could use [fetchRequestBlocks](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.html#//api/name/fetchRequestBlocks) in order to provide RestKit with the information required to handle this, but this would result in the object being deleted which may not be what you want.

Comment: Thanks! I did report this within one already existing issue which might be related to this. https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/669#issuecomment-25571841

I am now looking at directly editing the code in RKRelationshipConnectionOperation, it seems like the bug is in findConnectedValueForConnection:(RKConnectionDescription *)connection shouldConnect:(BOOL *)shouldConnectRelationship which is setting shouldConnectRelationship to NO. This might be a cleaner solution...let me know if you have any suggestions ;) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually I meant that the issue might be in this method in RKRelationshipConnectionOperation, which is setting shouldConnectRelationship  to NO:
- (id)findConnectedValueForConnection:(RKConnectionDescription *)connection shouldConnect:(BOOL *)shouldConnectRelationship